# Magento 2 and third parts daily data import

Tags: php, magento, interface, magento2, magmi

now I use Magento 1 and use Magmi for import data ( csv ) from third parts software.

I need to switch to Magento 2 and I know Magmi it's not available.

What do you use for import daily data into Magento 2? 
Do you use custom php interface ( with native Classes ), or there is something like Magmi?

P.S: we often use M2E for interface Amazon and Ebay.

Stef.

Comment: I always felt that 3rd party imports are never able to properly import data. Simply they are built to cover some general case and data imports usually have some business logic related to them. I know I wasn't really helpful, but that's just my two cents. :)

Comment: In our commercial extension for M2 we offer all MAGMI features and more https://firebearstudio.com/the-improved-import.html